# StringOutOfBoundsException for substring

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to the run the following on a text file (sample.text) that contains the following lines:

personPersistenceType=SQLite3
personDbConnectionString=person.sqlite3

However I'm getting an StringOutOfBoundsException (result -1). I understand that it means it can't find the = symbol, but I'm not sure why. I'm trying to get everything before the = symbol to be a String key and everything after the = symbol for a String value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextReader {

    private Scanner input = new Scanner("sample.txt");

    public void loadFile(){
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            String line = input.nextLine(); //acquires line
            String key = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('=')); //key
            String value = line.substring(line.indexOf('=') + 1); //value
            config.setProperty(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
new Scanner("sample.txt");
```

You are passing a String not a file location in the constructor thus giving you `StringOutOfBoundsException`

**solution:**

you need to add the file location inside the scanner by passing the File class in the constructor of the `Scanner`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt"));
```

By the way your implementation work for parsing the String.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the line contains an `=`, if there is a blank line (or a line without an equals) you will get that exception.

```
while (input.hasNextLine()){
  String line = input.nextLine(); //acquires line
  int pos = line.indexOf('=');
  if (pos < 0) { // <-- no equal sign, skip the line.
    continue;
  }
  String key = line.substring(0, pos); //key
  // Also, need to check if pos + 1 < line.length()
  String value = (pos + 1 < line.length()) ? line.substring(pos + 1) : "";
  config.setProperty(key, value);
}
```